DataTrigger doesn't change Rectangle background color on iOS
I have a Rectangle defined in XAML, and I want to adjust its color based on a Data Trigger. I started with something simple like this.
 <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="#00FF00">
     <Rectangle.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger TargetType="Rectangle" Binding="{Binding Cancelled}" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#FF0000" />
         </DataTrigger>
     </Rectangle.Triggers>
</Rectangle>

This works on Android, but on iOS the color is always #00FF00.
Cancelled is a nullable Boolean (bool?) in my viewmodel. I have verified that the value is indeed set to true. I am able to use the Cancelled binding on other Views to control things like visibility. For example, this works as expected.
 <Label IsVisible="{Binding Cancelled}" Text="Canceled" />

The last iteration in my attempt to make this works looks like this.
<Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Column="0">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Rectangle" Binding="{Binding Cancelled}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#0000FF" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Rectangle" Binding="{Binding Cancelled}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#00FF00" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Rectangle" Binding="{Binding Cancelled}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#FF0000" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
    
</Rectangle>


But, the color is still always #00FF00 on iOS. This issue seems to only affect BackgroundColor. For example, this trigger works as expected.
<Rectangle.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger TargetType="Rectangle" Binding="{Binding Cancelled}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="500" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Rectangle.Triggers>


I tried using Background instead of BackgroundColor but it still didn't work.

I don't think there's anything wrong with your DataTrigger. Typically when one encounters platform inconsistencies, or even inconsistencies between Debug and Release builds they often boil down to BindingContext problems. Typically they can be resolved by the explicit setting of x:DataType, or the explicit setting of Binding Source.

From the Rectangle doc

To paint the inside of the rectangle, set its Fill property to a Brush-derived object.

So you may use Fill property instead of BackgroundColor,
            <Rectangle.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Rectangle" Binding="{Binding Cancelled}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF0000" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Rectangle.Triggers> 

Please let me know if you have any question.
